# Graphhopper - Travel Times Between All 30,000 Visible Zip Codes?

Tags: graphhopper

I'd like to calculate the matrix of travel times between US zipcodes. There are about 30k visible zipcodes, so this is 900 million calculations (or 450 million assuming travel time is the same in both directions).

I haven't used graphhopper before but it seems suited to the task. My question are:

- What's the best way of doing it?
- Will this overload the graphhopper servers?
- How long will it take?

I can supply latitude and longitude for each pair of zip codes.

Thanks - Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not tested GraphHopper yet for these large amount of points, but it should be possible.

> What's the best way of doing it?

It would be probably faster if you avoid the HTTP overhead and use the Java lib directly like in [this example](https://github.com/karussell/optaplanner-graphhopper-example/blob/master/src/main/java/com/graphhopper/optaplanner/Main.java#L45). Be sure to assign enough RAM as the matrix itself is already 2g if you only use a short value for the distance or time. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25648425/how-does-graphhopper-handle-a-point-on-a-highway-intersections).

> Will this overload the graphhopper servers?

The API is not allowed to be used without an API key which you can grab [here](https://graphhopper.com/#enterprise). Or set up your own GraphHopper server.

> How long will it take?

Will take probably some days though.

*Warning* - enterprisy note: we provide support to setup your servers or for your usecase. And also we sell a matrix add-on which makes those calculations at least 10 times faster.